# Ripple with Full Alpha Compose Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, ripple, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a request to make the ripples with full Alpha in dark mode for our new jetpack compose screens. Is this possible?

I have defined a ripple theme like below, but it seems the ripple alpha is clamped somewhere in the ripple drawable and the ripple alpha comes through at around 50%.

Would a full ripple alpha block out all of the content on the View it is being displayed on and the clamping is a feature of the ripple?

```
object BlueRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() =
        RippleTheme.defaultRippleColor(
            AppTheme.colors.rippleSurface,
            lightTheme = true
        )

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha {
        return if (AppTheme.colors.isLight) {
            RippleTheme.defaultRippleAlpha(
                AppTheme.colors.rippleSurface,
                lightTheme = true
            )
        } else {
            RippleAlpha(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
        }
    }
}
```